# Script to add day not date to filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, dayofweek

I need to create a script batch, PowerShell or VB to add the day of the week to the filename.

For example, there are 4 files and all need to have MON apended to the front on Mondays, TUE on Tuesdays, WED on Wednesdays, etc.

Can anyone assist with this please?

Answer (score 7):

```
$dow = (Get-Date -f ddd).ToUpper()
$fileName = "${dow}_your_file_name.txt "

THU_your_file_name.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the VBScript Docs or Google for details on the `Weekday()` and `WeekdayName()` functions used in:

```
Today = Date()
DayNum = Weekday(Today)
DayName = WeekdayName(DayNum, True)
WScript.Echo UCase(DayName) & "_" &  "somefile.txt"

THU_somefile.txt
```

**PS:**
Start here: [Functions (VBScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ca8tfek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Providing links to that documentation would be quite helpful. All of the top links Google gives are to W3Schools, which is not always the best source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's an answer for powershell and one for VBScript.  Here's one for Windows cmd batch.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=5" %%I in ('find "" "%date:~0,3%" 2^>^&1') do set day=%%I
ren "oldfile.txt" "%day%_oldfile.txt"
```

**Explanation**

```
:: DIRECTIVE          RESULT
:: --------------------------------------------------------
:: %date%             Thu 02/07/2013
:: %date:~0,3%        Thu
:: find "" "Thu"      error stating "File not found - THU"
:: --------------------------------------------------------
```

Then all that remains is to redirect the error from stderr to stdout and scrape the fifth token.

([source of idea](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php) to use `find` to convert to upper case)

Comment: though it relies on a specific format of the output of date, +1 for all the Blood, Sweat & Tears.

Answer (score 0):

if you choose VBScript, be careful with `WeekDayName` function as it related to regional language settings. For example, `Friday` is `Петък` (in Bulgarian), so in my system `WeekDayName` with abbreviate set to `True` will return `Пт`, not `Fri`.

```
WScript.Echo WeekDayAbbrENG()

Function WeekDayAbbrENG()
    Dim WDs
    WDs = Split("SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT")
    WeekDayAbbrENG = WDs(Weekday(Now) - 1)
End Function
```

[EDIT] Actually, the same problem appear with `Get-Date` in PowerShell.